# How to combine prediction intervals / forecast ranges?

Tags: forecasting, prediction-interval, aggregation

Our sales team is handing me a forecast with 'ranges' so to speak.

To keep it simple, say that the forecast for Product A for 2017 is 100k, but the sales team says this can be from 80k-120k likely. They don't really give an exact confidence interval here of course - just judgement.

For Product B, the forecast is 60k, but they say in likelihood it could range from 30k-90k. Again, no confidence intervals here.

Now if you were to combine these rough estimates into an expected range, of course you'd say we 'expect' based on this judgement that the combined forecast for A and B would be 160k, the middle of the estimates. However, what would the new likely interval be? I mean if you're assuming a normal distribution for both these 'ranges' they've provided, the likelihood of 110k and 210k would be very unlikely. But how exactly would you come up with a new pessimistic/ optimistic scenario? I know the fact that these are unclear ranges may be the problem. Should we assume they are 80% or 90% confidence intervals with a normal distribution and refactor from there? Still, I'm unsure (say there are 10 products) how to come up with a new range. Perhaps we're going about this wrong. Perhaps the forecasts should be aggregated and then a range created?

I'm not sure how to aggregate calculations with a highly judgmental forecast.

Comment: Just a note: "prediction interval" is a more relevant keyword than "confidence interval" in this context.

Comment: An important issue concerns the extent to which those forecasts might be linked.  For instance, the lower ends of each interval might be predicated on a gloomy economic outlook while the upper ends might depend on a rosy picture. What makes one forecast go up or down could affect the other in a similar way. If, on the other hand, the forecasts were for a product and its replacement, and the uncertainty was associated only with how much substitution might occur, then what makes one forecast go up would make the other go down. Can you provide relevant information about the linkage?

Comment: There would be no linkage. Complete independence. These 'products' are actually completely different. Some seasonal similarities might be observed by pure chance. My basic understanding is this: The way the sales team is describing the model is ignoring pooled variance. Say they give a range of estimates for 100 products, and they are all 80%-120% some number (that's the range). The aggregate forecast for the same prediction interval would not 80-120% the sum. Because the odd of all 100 products going to 80% are astronomically low. Pooled variance - the aggregate range would be super tight.